# Safety of action="" if source code is modified

Tags: php, html

I'm really curious in regards of `action=""`.

Can someone actually go into the web tool (f12) and change the path to something else? I do keep the `name=""` on every form unique but is this possible if i have the same for every form?

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of your question, but yes anyone can change the action attribute of a form.

Comment: Anyone can change the HTML on the client side, or even not use the HTML at all and just pass their own data. This is true of any HTML form.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, is there no way to protect myself from it except from using unique `name=""` attributes?

Comment: Yes, server-side validation/sanitation.  *Never* trust any client side input and check the data coming in.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you do - if you remove it, it can still be added. What will happen if someone changes the `action` is that the form will submit the data to another page. It would be the same if someone made a form on their own page, submitting data do your page. The important thing is to do server-side validation, and as Crackertastic said just before me, don't trust any kind of user-input.

Comment: Some one could download the form host it elsewhere and have it submit anywhere. .. but so what?

Comment: Worth noting that a blank action is technically invalid HTML, though a missing one is not.